# weird issue <= operator in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to assign a state to a register in a FSM machine @(posedge clk) and reset = 1. However, statement: state <= 2'b00; simply couldn't set state = 2'b00. I checked by debugging that this statement state <= 2'b00 did have been stepped over. I really don't know where the problem is.

I met similar problems in other situations when some registers couldn't be assigned a value using "<=", but some can be in the same always block.

These registers that couldn't take the values simply show as 2'bxx if they have two bits.

Does anybody know what could cause the problem?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your explanation, i suppose your code is something like this.

always@(posedge clk and reset = 1)
state <= 2'b00;

These are the mistakes you are doing.
1. Sensitivity list can't be a combination of edge triggered and level triggered signals. 
2. For conditional operation, you should use "==", not "=".

Ideal code for your operation is,

always@(posedge clk)
   if (reset == 1)
      state <= 2'b00;

Answer (score 0):

I actually used the same way as you use the clock and reset signal in my code. However, my problem is that I reset the state at the beginning of the always block. Then, in the case statement inside the same always block, I used the default case to put the state back to arbitrary state. I am still a little bit confused by this mistake. But, anyway, after I removed this default statement, everything goes back to normal.

Thanks.